# Shortcut method to find the front side bus and memory bus speed of your computer

Tags: windows, memory, motherboard, bus

I can easily find out the RAM, Processing Speed of my Windows computer by clicking the `Properties` section of `Computer`.

Is there any shortcut method similar to the above to find the **front side bus speed** , **memory bus speed** , **back side bus speed** of my computer beside checking out the model number of your computer's motherboard and search for the model number on the Internet .

I will not mind using a third party utility tool also.

Comment: What is wrong with `CPU-Z`?

Comment: @Ramhound whats that ??

Comment: Google, Bing, and Yahoo went into a bar....Oh wait...Whats the question?